# Concurrent incrementing of a int variable

Tags: c++, concurrency

A question from a job-interview

```
int count = 0;

void func1()
{
  for ( int i =0 ; i < 10; ++i )
    count = count + 1;
}

void func2()
{
  for ( int i =0 ; i < 10; ++i )
    count++;
}

void func3()
{
  for ( int i =0 ; i < 10; ++i )
    ++count;
}

int main()
{
  thread(func1);
  thread(func2);
  thread(func3);

  //joining all the threads

  return 0;
}
```

The question is: what's the range of values `count` might theoreticaly take? The upper bound apparently is 30, but what's the lower one? They told me it's `10`, but i'm not sure about it. Otherwise, why do we need memory barriers?

So, what's the lower bound of the range?

Comment: Data races are UB, as such any range is "valid".

Comment: If `int count` was replaced with `std::atomic<int> count`, then (I believe) that we no longer have undefined behavior.  Pre-increment and post-increment are atomic; but the `count = count + 1` would not be guaranteed to be atomic -- would that bring us back to UB, or just mean that we have unspecified behavior?

Comment: It's only unspecified, and in this case you actually may derive a possible range of values.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

James Kanze's answer is the right one for all practical purposes, but in this particular case, if the code is exactly as written and the `thread` used here is `std::thread` from C++11, the behavior is actually defined.

In particular, `thread(func1);` will start a thread running `func1`. Then, at the end of the expression, the temporary thread object will be destroyed, without join or detach having been called on it. So the thread is still joinable, and the standard defines that in such a case, the destructor calls `std::terminate`. (See [thread.thread.destr]: "If joinable() then terminate(), otherwise no effects.") So your program aborts.

Because this happens before the second thread is even started, there is no actual race condition - the first thread is the only one that ever touches count, if it even gets that far.

Comment: References to the standard are welcome. (very good point, otherwise)

Comment: @qdii Added standard quote.

Comment: Ah :) I found it too: Section 15.5.1, note 1, last bullet point. `when the destructor or the copy assignment operator is invoked on an object of type std::thread
that refers to a joinable thread` ... `In such cases, std::terminate() is called`

Comment: @SebastianRedl if i would create a named thread object(s) then there exists a race condition right?

Comment: @Koushik yes, exactly. Once you fix the problem of these things just being temporary, the code reverts to what was intended, which has the behavior James Kanze described.

Comment: It's interesting too because it involves observable behavior.  Otherwise, a compiler could see that `count` is never actually used, so the threads have no impact on observable behavior, and simply eliminate them.

Answer (score 16):

It's undefined behavior, so `count` could take on any value
imaginable.  Or the program could crash.

Comment: What if `int` is a single `word`?

Comment: I mean, wouldn't that mean, that the operation is atomic? (excluding `func1` actually)

Comment: It is not atomic as far as the standard is concerned.

Comment: @avakar - I never said anything about the standard. It's not portable, BUT I'm asking about the _specific_ case, when `int` is a single `word` and (if we exclude `func1`), aren't both post/pre-increment operations atomic? And if so, can't we actually define a range?

Comment: Modern x86 processors, never mind other types of processors (man of which are worse), makes no guarantee about atomic updates to ANY size of data, if there are multiple readers and multiple writers simultaneously. There is no way to tell which comes first, or what value count has at any given point. It is atomic in the sense that if you write a value and "win the race", the entire value is written - in other words, you won't get "half a write from one core and half a write from another core". But which read or write is first/last is impossible to say.

Comment: @MatsPetersson - "what value count has at any given point" - agreed. But I asked about the range, so doesn't "It is atomic in the sense that if you write a value and "win the race", the entire value is written" mean, that we can actually define a range in _this_ case only? (I'm tempted to risk and post this as a separate question :) )

Comment: It is not only about hardware architecture, the optimizer can do pretty strange things too. In particular, all functions can end up as "count += 10;". But anyway, it can do whatever it wants in the presence of a race.

Comment: Yes, but the range may not be what you obviously expect. Admittedly, it is LIKELY in the range 0..30 in the above example (assuming no crashing or other undefined behaviour takes over)

Comment: @KirilKirov Whether `int` is a single word or not changes nothing.  It's not difficult to imagine a case where a write that is concurrent to an access with another process will just hang.

Comment: @KirilKirov My point is that the behavior is undefined.  That anything can happen.  And that there are, or have been, real hardware where the given code could cause the system to hang.

Answer (score 4):

Starting with the easy part, the obvious upper bound is 30 since, if everything goes right, you have 3 calls to functions; each capable of incrementing `count` 10 times. Overall: 3*10=30.

Ad to the lower bound, they are correct and this is why - the worst-case scenario is that each time that one thread tries to increment `count`, the other  threads will be doing so at exactly the same time. Keeping in mind that `++count` actually is the following pseudo code:

```
count_temp = count;
count_temp = count_temp+1;
count = count_temp;
```

It should be obvious that if they all perform the same code at the same time, you have only 10 real increments, since they all read the same initial value of `count` and all write back the same added value.

Comment: Undefined behavior is undefined. However this is well defined behavior as the range of possible outcomes is well defined. The counting is only going upwards.

Comment: Because it's wrong. Concurrent modification is undefined behavior, and no amount of reasoning will get you an upper or lower bound on the possible values of count.

Comment: @levengli what you are saying is logical, and it's probably true! But data races are undefined behavior and, by definition, no assumption can be made to what will happen when they occur.

Comment: You are mistaken on this specific account. I know that the textbook answer is what you gave, however this is a very simplified question in which the outcome is, indeed, defined

Comment: It is defined, as I'm going to explain in the answer I'm currently writing, but not in the way you think.

Comment: Inspite of UB, can't there be "chache tricks"? Like 1) count is loaded into CPU1 2) CPU1 incs it 3) ``count`` is loaded into CPU2 3) CPU1 stores ``count`` 4) CPU2 incs count 5) CPU2 stores count? So, we have one "missed" incrementing?

Comment: What part of "undefined" is so hard to understand?

Comment: @SebastianRedl, being obnoxious (a la "what part of...") is not being right. You are making all sorts of assumptions regarding the threading mechanism; whereas they are not necessarily true in this case.
A simple threading mechanism; which forks 3 different functions, should result at anything 10<=count<=30.

Comment: @levengli I have no idea what you're talking about. C++ has exactly one threading mechanism, and that one is defined by the official C++ standard to work in such a way that concurrent modification of shared, non-atomic variables is completely undefined behavior. If you want "possible range of values", you need to use Java.

Comment: The standard is there to help design, not debug. If you had code on a modern x86 system with this bug, then the answer is 10 to 30, period.

Comment: @levengli That's simply incorrect.  I've encountered machines where the code could hang, for example, and it's not hard to imagine machines where values considerably larger or smaller can occur.

Comment: @ActiveTrayPrntrTagDataStrDrvr And that helps you debug how, exactly? If you already know the code that has the race condition, just fix the race condition. If you see weird behavior, are you really going to track it down to "`count` is always between 10 and 30, let's look for code that could have this effect"?

Comment: The question was asked in the context of a job interview and should be answered accordingly.

Comment: Right, because we live in a perfect world, where a quick look into the C++ standard book automagically populates our watch window and e-mails us the faulty memory snapshots with the rogue side-effects marked in yellow? Not.

Comment: @levengli In the context of a job interview, the definite answer should be "anything can happen, because the code has UB". Pointing out that code has UB is fairly important. The interviewer should be ashamed of claiming that the bounds are 10 and 30 respectively.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, I'd like to thank you guys for giving me reason me to read the [standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2011/n3242.pdf) in depth. I would not be able to continue this debate otherwise.

The standard states quite clearly in section 1.10 clause 21: `The execution of a program contains a data race if it contains two conflicting actions in different threads, at least one of which is not atomic, and neither happens before the other. Any such data race results in undefined behavior.`

However, the term `undefined behavior` is also defined in the standard, section 1.3.24: `behavior for which this International Standard imposes no requirements... Permissible undefined behavior ranges from ignoring the situation completely with unpredictable results, to behaving during translation or program execution in a documented manner characteristic of the environment...`

Taking Sebasian's answer regarding `std::terminate` into account, and working under the assumption that these threads will not throw an exception thereby causing premature termination; while the standard doesn't define the result - it is fairly evident what it may be because of the simplicity of the algorithm. In other words, while the 100% accurate answer would be that the result is undefined - I still maintain that the range of possible outcomes is well defined and is 10-30 due to the `characteristic of the environment`.

BTW - I really wanted to make this a comment instead of another answer, however it was too long

Comment: For your defence i say that the answer you gave is the exactly one those guys want to get :-)